# Horizontal GridView with customAdaptor not displaying properly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridview

I want to display a single row of 5 images which then I can click on, this is what I hope to get:

[1][2][3][4][5]

This is what I actually get:"____" is a large, long blank area

[1]________________________

[2]________________________

[3]________________________

[4]________________________

[5]________________________

At first I thought there was something up with the orientation so I tried both "horizontal" and "vertical" but nothing worked.

Here is the adaptor code:

```
public class CustomTopGridMenuAdaptor extends BaseAdapter {

private Context mContext;

private final int[] gridViewImageId;
private ImageView imageViewAndroid;

public CustomTopGridMenuAdaptor(Context context, int[] gridViewImageId) {
    mContext = context;
    this.gridViewImageId = gridViewImageId;}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return gridViewImageId.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return null;
}

public void setImageSource (int i,ImageView v){
    imageViewAndroid.setImageResource(gridViewImageId[i]);
}


@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View gridViewAndroid;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null) {
                gridViewAndroid = new View(mContext);
                gridViewAndroid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.android_custom_gridview_layout_top, null);


imageViewAndroid = (ImageView) 
gridViewAndroid.findViewById(R.id.android_gridview_image_top);
                setImageSource(i,imageViewAndroid);

} else {
            gridViewAndroid = (View) convertView;
        }


    return gridViewAndroid;
}
```

}

As far as it goes the adaptor is working just fine.

This is the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/android_custom_gridview_layout_top"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/android_gridview_image_top"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the xml segment in the activity layout, where the menu will be displayed:

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/android_gridview_menu_top"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="196dp">
```

Can you tell me why it's not working?

Comment: please provide the code where you initialize the adapter and setting adapetr to recyclerView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `android:numColumns="2"` in your GridView if you want 5 then change the `android:numColumns="5"`

```
<GridView
android:id="@+id/android_gridview_menu_top"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:numColumns="2"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
android:layout_marginStart="196dp">
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that gridviews can be made horizontally scrollable. Android has provided `HorizontalScrollView` it will scroll your view horizontaly. try this.

```
<HorizontalScrollView
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">

      <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:orientation="horizontal">

          <GridView
             android:id="@+id/gridView"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content">
          </GridView>

      </LinearLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Happy coding!!